# Position absolute without a set top property gives inconsistent rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working locally on a personal project, and I started noticing my navigation disappearing sometimes when refreshing.

Here is a video of the navigation disappearing without me doing anything else than executing a normal refresh in Google Chrome https://gfycat.com/ElegantNaiveKid

If I refresh again, the navigation comes back to the normal position.

looked at my CSS and saw that my navigation had `position: absolute;` and `right: 0px;`, but the `top` property was not set.

When I write  `top: 0px;` the inconsistent rendering stops.

This codepen is a litteral copy of the top of my page, with the exception of the `<head>`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNXWKr

On my page the navigation is made with php like this:

```
<?php 
    $pages = [
        "work" => "Work",
        "about" => "About",
        "contact" => "Contact",
        "blog" => "Blog"
    ];
?>
<div class="navigation-container">
    <div class="navigation centered">
        <div class="signature"><a href="<?php echo $pageURL ?>"></a></div>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                foreach ($pages as $pageLink => $pageName) {
                    echo "<li><a href='$pageURL/$pageLink'>$pageName</a></li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the site gets it like this: `<?php require_once("elements/navigation.php") ?>`

**So anyone knows why this happens? Is this a bug?**

Comment: Possibly a caching issue? Have you tried a hard reset? Open your dev console and hold down the refresh button. Delete the page cache and reload.

Comment: @JDB I'm pretty sure it's not the cache. Hard refresh in incognito mode is still inconsistent without the top property set.
Looking at the CSS, it stays the same, but if I toggle position: absolute; off and back on with Chrome Dev console, it comes back to it's normal position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing an artifact due to the part of the CSS specification related to absolute positioning and the *static-position containing block*.

If the offsets are not specified in your CSS for `position: absolute`, then the browser computes the static-position containing block and uses that positioning for the offsets.

However, the CSS specification does not really say precisely how to determine the static-position containing block, and as a result, different browsers do it differently.  It may be that Chrome has a somewhat fuzzy algorithm for the static-position computation and the result varies with refreshing the page.

As you notice, if you specify the `top` offset, the problem goes away because the static-position computation does not come into play.

You are not doing anything wrong, but just seeing the effects of a somewhat obscure part of the CSS specification.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

Comment: CSS really likes being weird sometimes, so this sounds about right. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use absolute positioning. In your gif, as you inspect the list items, you can see that they are below that top header. Or you can keep the absolute positioning and set a high z-index. Have you looked at this issue in other browsers?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using absolute positioning when the parent container is set to relative. The correct position is the one that first shows in the video, then sometimes (every 5th refresh or so), it falls down.

This stops happening if I set top property  to 0.

Just tested in Firefox, it does not happen there. I'm not using any webkit specific css